# If I run multiple test cases together, do I need to clear previous state or will Angular do it automatically?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have multiple test cases covering different components and in different specs. Each of them run successfully but when I run them together, some of them randomly fail, some for weird reasons like a `css-selector` isn't found

```
let routerElement = contentComponentElement.querySelector("router-outlet");
    expect(routerElement).toBeTruthy(); //fails sometimes
```

Could it be possible that because I am running them together, a test case is picking residue or left-over state of the previous test case? Is it possible to clear all the previous data/html etc. before running a new test case?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was some of the test cases used `Observables` and I wasn't waiting for the `Observables` to finish before moving to the next test case. I started calling `done` for such test cases and now things are in order.